# Принципы ООП в Java

Tags: java, ооп

У меня есть классы рабочих, у каждого есть метод, увеличивающий кол. определенного ресурса. В классе `Resources` есть закрытые интовые статик поля обозначающие кол. каждого ресурса, а так-же геттеры, сеттеры.

Как правильно сделать увеличение ресурса рабочим?

Делать в классе рабочего инстанс `Resources`, из инстанса получать и увеличивать количество ресурса или же не делать инстанс и обращаться через открытые методы `Resources.getWoodAmount()` и `Resources.setWoodAmount()`?

Comment: почему не сделать внутри `Resources` метод при визове которого будет увеличивася нужное значение

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос, и неясен контекст. Можно сделать многими разными способами, но чтобы дать какой-то осмысленный ответ, ситуацию надо понимать лучше, чем ее можно понять из вашего вопроса. В частности, ресурс принадлежит всему классу рабочих, или есть экземпляры рабочих, и у каждого из них свое количество ресурса?